# Is there any ways to get data from Firebase Analytics Log Events in real time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'd like to make a dashboard with the data that I stored in Firebase Analytics Log Events.

The only way I can use the data is downloading CSV file from each event and move the useful data to my database one by one and customise them.

But I want to fetch the data of Firebase Events directly to my dashboard for real time data. Is it possible?

Firebase Events is belong to Firebase Analytics. Check here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Firebase Events"?   That's not a Firebase product.

Comment: @DougStevenson Firebase Events from Analytics. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android